# For Each Loop in VB.net stuck in a condition statement

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write a code using vb.net but I'm stuck in a `For Each` loop and I hope that someone can help.

I'm trying to search for files by extension and I used a `For Each` loop as follows:

```
For Each XMLLFILE In Directory.GetFiles(directoryName, "*.xmll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
```

After that, I'm trying to add a condition to delete the searched files and if not, to popup a message that there are no files found. The rest of the code is:

```
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(XMLLFILE) Then
        File.Delete(XMLLFILE)
        MsgBox("Files Deleted !", vbOKOnly, "DeleteXMLL Files")
    Else
        MsgBox("There's No files to be Deleted !", vbOKOnly, "DeleteXMLL Files")
    End If
    Exit For
Next
End If
```

I'm getting a message box for each time file is deleted (repeatedly), if there are no files inside the folder, I got no message box at all.

Can anyone help with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GetFiles()` method returns the files that *do exist* in that folder. Your `If` statement checks if each of those files exists, which doesn't make sense (because we already know they do). Instead, you should check whether or not `GetFiles()` returns any files.

Try something like the following:

```
' Find the files and store them in a String array.
Dim filesToDelete As String() = 
    Directory.GetFiles(directoryName, "*.xmll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)

' If some files are found,...
If filesToDelete.Any() Then
    ' Delete each one of them...
    For Each XMLLFILE In filesToDelete
        File.Delete(XMLLFILE)
    Next
    ' ..and then display a success message.
    MsgBox("Files Deleted!", vbOKOnly, "DeleteXMLL Files")
Else
    ' If not, display a different message.
    MsgBox("There are No files to be Deleted!", vbOKOnly, "DeleteXMLL Files")
End If
```